# How to run a file path in powershell with it being taken as Unicode

Tags: python, powershell, path

So I have this code which I am using to import an excel file with pandas:

```
excelFilePath = ('C:\Users\pa4167\autoModTest\excelTrial') #
dfr = pd.read_excel(excelFilePath)
```

but when I try to run the code in powershell (its needed for this project) the code it taken as unicode and I tried to but r'' so that the code would be taken as raw code but then the file path messes up in powershell and it cannot find the file. The code should be written into the python file and simply executed in power shell so Get-item does not work.

I have tried all the solutions like using / or \ or simply r but each time it can not find the file and I read that pandas starts at you current directory so I tried simply putting the file name but powershell could not find it either. I need a way to run the code and for powershell to recognize the filepath to gab the excel file. I need the code to run in the python and only use the powershell sto run the full program. I have tried / \ and r already and cant figure out a way for powershell to not take it as unicode or still be able to find the file in the file path.

Comment: try change system variable PYTHONUTF8 or change path split \ by / or \\

Comment: Try with the \\, it should be readable both by python and windows